# How to add gradient overlay over image?

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

```
 #artist-image-container{
      background-image:
      radial-gradient(rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), #181c44),url('./yo\ yo\ honey\ singh.jpg');
      width: 34%;
      min-width: 34%;
      min-height: 300px;
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 20px;
 }
```

I have written this code but I want to add radial gradient as shown in image at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: you need to set the position too . it could be something alike `background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0% , rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), #181c44 80%);` see for more infos : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean like that

```css
#img{
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 153, 0.8)),
    url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```